# Import for geotools not being resolved after adding the dependency to pom.xml in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, geotools

I have tried to add geotools to my pom.xml using the following guides:

```
https://www.baeldung.com/geo-tools
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html
```

Neither methods worked after waiting for the workspace to be built and for everything to load. I have tried clean but that did not resolve anything and I have tried to remove the project from the workspace and add it back and it did not work. Other dependencies I have tried to import have worked fine but the geotools imports will not be resolved no matter what I have tried. Below is my current pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.blavelle.rest.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restful-web-services</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>15.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>opengeo</id>
            <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the OpenGeo repository?

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Does your maven `settings.xml` file by any chance contain one or more `<mirror>` entries? If it contains a reference to a company artifactory/nexus mirror, access might be restricted to unknown repositories for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [GeoTools instructions](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html) you will see that you need these repositories:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

I have no idea how the [other site](https://www.baeldung.com/geo-tools) managed to go so wrong when simply copying an [existing GeoTools tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html).

And finally, 15.2 is a fairly old version, you'd be better off starting with the current stable version ([20.3](https://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2019/03/geotools-203-released.html)),